# Find object from json

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, dictionary, search

I have one json looks like this.

```
{
  "countrycode" : 
  [["11","","91","INDIA"," New Delhi"],
  ["112","Mahanagar Telephone Nigam Ltd (MTNL]","91","INDIA"," New Delhi"],
  ["113","Reliance Communications Ltd","91","INDIA"," New Delhi"],
  ["114","Bharti Airtel Ltd","91","INDIA"," New Delhi"],
  ["115","Sistema Shyam TeleServices Ltd (MTS]","91","INDIA"," New Delhi"],
  ["122","","91","INDIA"," Hapur  Ghaziabad"],
  ["1222","Bharat Sanchar Nigam Ltd (BSNL]","91","INDIA"," Hapur  Ghaziabad"],
  ["1223","Reliance Communications Ltd","91","INDIA"," Hapur  Ghaziabad"]]
}
```

and I want to find perfect matched record with first row of json with my value. My value may be "1178920" or "1130123" or "1151593248" or "1223798".

If my value is 1223798 then return me:

```
["1223","Reliance Communications Ltd","91","INDIA"," Hapur  Ghaziabad"]]
```

I can't find a way. Please help me.

Comment: Is your json correct. Because in your json  only first Array object contain another array check that.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried, and describe what it did incorrectly

Comment: @NiravDoctorwala my json is correct please check on http://jsonlint.com/ for verify.

Comment: I know it is correct but your first object only contain another array thats why i'm asking to you check that

Comment: do you want value for "1223798" or only "1223"? if for "1223798" then what's the value "798" after "1223"? how you are creating that search string?

Comment: @NiravDoctorwala i have json this formate i can't change because of some problem. Can say me which type of json you want?

Comment: I want result for "1223798" not for "1223".

Comment: @Feldur i have try by for loop. but i think is not correct way.

Comment: How many letter you want to match with ? e.g first three or four

Comment: @Mahesh is not fix it may be 2 digit to 10 digit.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSPredicate *predicateString = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF BEGINSWITH %@", @"1223"];
NSArray *newarr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[dict valueForKey:@"countrycode"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicateString]];
```

Hope this one help you.

Comment: Your answer is correct but while enter value like "1223" it is not working on while value will "1223456712"

Comment: Your solution return records like "251223" also. bcoz string contain our value. Compulsory value on prifix only.

Comment: @PramodTapaniya now try again with my editable answer... hope this time it will be right

Answer (score -2):

The way of get the things as you want it :

```
Nsarray * object = [NSArray from countrycode]

For (index = 0: index<object; index++ )
{
    NSArray * objectTest = object[index];

    NSString * arrValue = objectTest[0];

   if ([arrValue rangeOfString:@"YourValue"].location == NSNotFound) {
         NSLog(@"string does not contain Value");
   } else {
         NSLog(@"string contains Value!");
   }

}
```